# Is the "categories" tag too broad? What should its wiki page report?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request, burninate-request

I noticed that there are 415 questions tagged with [categories](/questions/tagged/categories), which include questions about Objective-C categories, the `<optgroup>`/`<option>` tags, WordPress's categories, Magento's categories, etc.

Isn't the tag too broadly used? While I can imagine a definition of *categories* that includes all the specific definitions, is the tag really useful? Are there experts that follow that tag, and who are able to answer to every question tagged [categories](/questions/tagged/categories)?

Comment: Nobody follows it. (Hover over the tag on SO and wait for the JavaScript popup.)

Comment: The tag has 0 followers, for your last sentence. I suppose it could use disambiguating. (Ah, @Bill is half a minute faster than me.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard The last question was rhetorical. `:-)`